# Response 409, Shared Preference Manager

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem. If my device is registered in the server the server generates 409 response. So when I register my device to the server I am saving the ID response generated by the server in the shared preference manager. But for some reason the ID is not getting stored in the shared preference manager. I am new to android development and I don't know what to do now. Please help me with this issue.

Shared Preference Manager

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "fcmsharedprefdemo";

    private static Context mCtx;
    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized  SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null)
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        return mInstance;
    }


    public boolean storeDeviceId(String deviceId){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(d_Id, deviceId);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }
    public String getDeviceId(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(d_Id, null);
    }

}
```

This is my Shared Preference Manager and I am adding the Main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public static String deviceId = "";
    public static Context context;
    public SharedPrefManager sharedInst;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    sharedInst = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IMEI_NUMBER = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    if(sharedInst.getDeviceId() == null){
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", IMEI_NUMBER);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(server_url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String s = "id";
                        try {
                            deviceId = response.getString(s);
                            sharedInst.storeDeviceId(deviceId);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );
        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
    Log.d("deviceID:", sharedInst.getDeviceId());
}
```

Shared preference Manager just stores the device's ID and get devicesID also it stores fcm tokens and gets fcm tokens.

In my code I am trying to save the deviceId that I got as response from the server. But the problem i am facing is that the deviceId is not getting stored for some reason. Can some android guru help me in solving this issue, why is the deviceId not getting stored. Am I missing something obvious here. Is there anything that I have to add to the code. Am I not generating the instances correctly and that is the reason the device ID is not getting generated. I could see that the call is made properly to the server and the server is generating the deviceId also.

Also can somebody tell me how can I handle responses like 409, I want my program to run inspite of getting those responses.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Wow that's a lot of code. You are more likely to get an answer if you include the minimum amount of code needed to replicate your error

Comment: Can yo uplease help me now if possible, why is the deviceId not getting stored. It gives null

Answer (score 0):

I realized where the problem is! The problem is with volley. I am adding 3 requests to the queue and the second and third requests are being done after the first request is made. But the problem is the second and third requests depend on the first request response. That is why my program is stopping and giving me an error.

Can somebody help me with how to send a request in volley only after getting response. Right now each request is added to the queue but what I need is I should send the next two requests after receiving response from the first one.

Here is my volleyManager code

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static ApplicationController sInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
}


public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}


public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

    VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TAG);

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}


public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
    }

}
```

Please let me know how to do it.